# Azure SQL Database: "No columns were selected" when calling a stored procedure using Dapper

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, dapper

I have a really simple stored procedure in Azure SQL Database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spfindPartialIdentity 
    @ClientId nvarchar(50),
    @ExternalId nvarchar(250)
AS BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT 
       ClientId, ExternalId 
   FROM 
       [dbo].[PartialIdentities] 
   WHERE 
       ClientId = @ClientId AND ExternalId = @ExternalId
END
```

and I invoke it using Dapper from my repository:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReportingDB"].ConnectionString))
{
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    var res = await conn.QueryAsync<PartialIdentity>("dbo.spfindPartialIdentity", 
                                                      new { ClientId = clientId, ExternalId = externalId }, 
                                                      commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
                                                      commandTimeout: GetCommandTimeout());

    return res.ToList();
}
```

Really straightforward. I works fine, BUT when the stored procedure returns no results I got a

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Dapper.dll, "No columns were selected"

exception when calling `QueryAsync()`. My DTO is really simple as well:

```
public class PartialIdentity
{
    public PartialIdentity(string clientId, string externalId)
    {
        this.ClientId = clientId;
        this.ExternalId = externalId;
    }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried `QueryMultipleAsync()` as well, same result.

What is the problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be bug in my SP, the Dapper code was just fine. The SP was actually a bit more complex (with a some nested IF-THEN-ELSE), and when no records matched the condition it did not do anything, did not return anything and the poor Dapper did not know how to map that to the DTO - hence the exception. Duh! Silly me! Documenting that in case someone else have a similar case.